# Search for line starting with phrase and swap with next line?

Tags: shell, text, gnu, data-manipulation

Supposing I have a file like this:

```
Stuff here
TERM here
Other stuff
Stuff here
TERM HERE
Additional stuff
End of stuff
```

Is there a Linux command line tool that will find all the lines that start with `TERM` and swap that entire line with the next line, so as to produce:

```
Stuff here
Other stuff
TERM here
Stuff here
Additional stuff
TERM HERE
End of stuff
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Vim non-interactively as `vim -e` or just `ex` with this command:

```
ex filename -u NONE -c 'g/^TERM/del | put' -c 'wq'
```

Explanation:

- `ex filename`: Non-interactively edit `filename`
- `-u NONE`: Don't load a vimrc file.
- `-c`: Run the following command after loading the file
- `g`: The `:global` command. It searches for a pattern, then performs a command at each place it finds it.
- `/^TERM/`: The pattern to search for. `^` is a special character that matches the start of a line. `/`s are used to delimit the pattern.
- `del`: Deletes the current line.
- `|`: Separates commands. In this case, `del` and `put`. Both are still part of the `g` command.
- `put`: Pastes the deleted line after the current line.
- `wq`: Write the file to disk and quit. This has to be put as a separate `-c` argument instead of separated with `|` like `put`, because it would otherwise quit after only doing the first matching line.

Comment: Nice!! Thanks very much. Sorry I apparently don't have enough reputation points to upvote the answer, I'd appreciate it if somebody else could do so. Works great.